# Unrecognized field at: jerseyClient dropwizard yml?

Tags: java, yaml, dropwizard

My dropwizard server needs to call external REST resource, for that, I plan to use Jersey Client, For that, I have added following dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

Then I added yml configurations as follows:

```
jerseyClient:
  minThreads: 1
  maxThreads: 128
  workQueueSize: 8
  gzipEnabled: true
  gzipEnabledForRequests: true
  chunkedEncodingEnabled: true
```

In my `WebConfiguration` class I added the following code:

```
@Valid
    @NotNull
    private JerseyClientConfiguration jerseyClient = new JerseyClientConfiguration();

    @JsonProperty("jerseyClient")
    public JerseyClientConfiguration getJerseyClientConfiguration() {
        return this.jerseyClient;
    }
```

When I try running my WebApplication I get the following error:

```
api.yml has an error:
  * Unrecognized field at: jerseyClient
    Did you mean?:
      - server
      - assets
      - logging
      - metrics
      - database
        [1 more]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

What is wrong here ? Is the dropwizard client not allowed on dropwizard server ? Or it's simply indentation problem ?

***Update:***

After failing to add jerseyClient configuration I tried adding [HttpClient](https://www.dropwizard.io/0.6.2/manual/client.html#man-client-apache) it worked for me.

Comment: Shouldn't you be defining `@JsonProperty` on setter? As in this case, jackson is trying to de-serialize config from yaml to config bean.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add setter for with `@JsonProperty` in `Configuration` extended file.

This worked for me.

In `Configration` file

```
@Valid
@NotNull
private JerseyClientConfiguration jerseyClient = new JerseyClientConfiguration();

@JsonProperty("jerseyClient")
public JerseyClientConfiguration getJerseyClientConfiguration() {
    return jerseyClient;
}

@JsonProperty("jerseyClient")
public void setJerseyClientConfiguration(JerseyClientConfiguration jerseyClient) {
    this.jerseyClient = jerseyClient;
}
```

In `config.yml` file.

```
jerseyClient:
  minThreads: 2
  maxThreads: 128
  workQueueSize: 8
  gzipEnabled: true
  gzipEnabledForRequests: true
  chunkedEncodingEnabled: true
server:
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8085
```